# how to set kendo ui grid readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

When I used Kendo UI Grid component, I have problem to make readonly or disabled the Grid component.

I have tried with JQuery ( using class .k-button and/or 
.k-button-icontext) to set readonly or disabled.

The toolbutton works, but
the in-row Edit and Delete buttons may not be changed (always clickable).
Do you have any trick to achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These solutions are given on Kendo Website they will get you through this

[Grid / Editing custom editor](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom) also according to them "**Making individual rows** read-only is not supported out of the box. It is possible to define individual columns as editable: false in the DataSource's model"

Comment: hi, I found similar comments that it is not available. I just wanna make sure whether it could have been fixed or not. I am not sure what you mean by "false in the DataSource's model". What I need will be to toggle whether a kendo grid is editable (sometimes yes sometimes no). Even when it is not editable, the data has to appear in the grid, rather than make the grid empty or gone.

Comment: I was talking in the context of this link
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#schemamodel-objectkendodatamodel